# Titanium Developer v1.2.2 Emulator blank screen

Tags: android-emulator, titanium

Hi I am using windows 7 x32, the Titanium Developer v1.2.2 Emulator gives me a blank screen. How to fix this ?

```
[INFO] Launching Android emulator...one moment 
[INFO] Creating new Android Virtual Device (1 HVGA) 
[INFO] Building Testing for Android ... one moment 
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.6.2 (04/18/11 17:16 878906d) 
[INFO] Waiting for the Android Emulator to become available 
[ERROR] Timed out waiting for android.process.acore 
[INFO] Copying project resources.. 
[INFO] Tiapp.xml unchanged, skipping class generation 
[INFO] Compiling Javascript Resources ... [INFO] Compiling Android Resources... This could take some time 
[INFO] Installing application on device [ERROR] Failed installing com.cc: pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
```

Comment: I haven't done much Android programming but I'm told by fellow developers that TiStudio is the way better for Android development using Titanium

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening for a variety of reasons.

Try to delete the contents of /project_root/build/android/*

Then try and relaunch/rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success by starting the Android emulator prior to doing a build. Works on my mac. Plus the delete the contents of the /build/android/ folder is a good suggestion.